# Find $\lim \frac{n!}{2^n+1}$ (or find whether $\sum \frac{n!}{2^n+1}$ converges)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know this function fails the limit test so I was wondering how to calculate a limit for a factorial. I tried to calculate the limit for $\frac{n}{2^n+1}$ but it passes the test. It also converges so it doesn't tell me much. I tried to find a function that was greater than this one and tried with 
$$\frac{n^2}{2^n+1}$$

not sure if $n^2>n! \forall n $ but it converges.

What do I do?

Comment: As a tiny suggestion: $2\cdot 2^n \gt 2^n+1$ for all $n$, so $\frac{n!}{2\cdot 2^n}\lt \frac{n!}{2^n+1}$ for all $n$; try applying the ratio test to that function.

Comment: Stirling's formula might help you here.  But, really, just trying the first few values should tell you the answer.

Comment: As you go from $n$ to $n+1$, the numerator is multiplied by $n+1$, while the denominator is only (approximately) multiplied by 2.  This shows that the $n-$th term goes to infinity.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I'm going to take a guess and say it diverges... or it wouldn't be relevant that it's lesser than the given one. I'll try for practice though

Comment: FYI, $n^2\in\mathcal O\left(n!\right)$, i.e., $n! > n^2$ as $n\to\infty$. In fact, this is true $\forall n > 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the quotient test: since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{(n+1)!}{2^{n+1}+1}}{\frac{n!}{2^n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\frac{2^n+1}{2^{n+1}+1}=\infty,$$the series diverges.

Comment: I had used it before but thought the limit couldn't be infinity... thanks, that just solved a bunch of other exercises I was stuck on for that reason

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: By the way, does that also apply to Cauchy's criteria?

Comment: Yes, Cauchy's criteria can be used to prove that the series diverges, but that looks quite artificial to me.

Comment: Why does it look artificial to you?

Comment: Because I am able to do it only using the fact that the limit that I computed in my answer is greater than $1$. But then it is more natural to use the quotient test.